How can I make all the lines within the polygon turn gray in that region?
How can I make all the lines within the polygon turn gray in that region?
   points = {{-4, 5}, {-1, 2}, {1, 2}, {4, 4}, {4, 1/2}, {0, 1/2}, {-2, 
        1}, {-4, 5}};
    shape = ListLinePlot[points, PlotRange -> {{-4, 5}, {0, 5}}, 
       Filling -> {1 -> Axis}, 
       FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.2], Blue]];
    func = {x, 1 - 2 x, 3 + x};
    Show[shape, Plot[func, {x, -5, 5}]]


EDIT: The method by cvgmt works well. What if I have like more than 300 functions. Does anyone know a method that could speed up this?


RegionFunction with RegionMember.
To make difference color, we use ConditionalExpression.


"14.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"

poly = Polygon@points;
funs = {ConditionalExpression[#, ! ({x, #} ∈ poly)], 
     ConditionalExpression[#, ! {x, #} ∈ poly], 
     ConditionalExpression[#, ! ({x, #} ∈ poly)]} & /@ func;

Show[shape, Plot[funs // Evaluate, {x, -5, 5}], 
 Plot[#, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Gray], 
    RegionFunction -> 
     Function[{x}, Evaluate@RegionMember[poly,{x, #}]]] & /@
   func]



Thanks but somehow it doesn't work for me. And how can I keep these lines outside the polygon as well with their initial colors.
"14.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"

I succeeded in creating different colors using MapThread!

Please include poly = Polygon@points;
